# Refactoring logic inside if statement to bare minimum

Tags: javascript, math, logic, computer-science, permutation

Sometime ago I wrote an educational JavaScript application with SVG (*closed-source for a company*). At its most basic form the application consisted of two columns (*left and right*), and each column contained various geometric shapes (*squares, triangles, circles*, etc.)

Each geometric shape in one column could connect (*by drawing a line*) to another geometric shape in the opposite column. However, a shape in either column could have one or many connections to/from it, depending on its settings.

So a shape with a setting of `{multiple: false}` can only have one connection to it or from it. It doesn't matter whether the connection originated from it or from another shape to it; one connection means only one connection regardless of the origin.

The part of the code that connects the shapes by drawing a line is an overly complex if statement. Here it is:

```
if ((!sourceHasLines && !targetHasLines) ||
  (sourceHasLines && sourceCanMultiply && !targetHasLines) ||
  (sourceHasLines && sourceCanMultiply && targetHasLines && targetCanMultiply) ||
  (!sourceHasLines && !sourceCanMultiply && targetHasLines && targetCanMultiply) || 
  (!sourceHasLines && sourceCanMultiply && targetHasLines && targetCanMultiply)) {
    // Create a line only if one of the above comparisons succeeds
    connection = self.connect($source, $target);
}
```

- **Source** refers to a shape in one column and **target** to a shape in the opposite column.
- Users can initiate a connection from either column by first clicking one shape in the first column, and then by clicking another shape in the second column.
- Shapes in the same column cannot be connected.

Looking at the code now, I feel that the logic inside the if statement can probably be compressed down, and I have some ideas already. However, I have a feeling that this has to do with either permutations or some other CS related logic like Discrete Math. I'm mostly self-taught, so I'd like to see how someone would approach this and refactor the above if statement.

Please note that the code works great but I'm wondering how it could be improved. Here is a screenshot of a prototype with top/bottom rows instead of left/right columns:

[image: Connect top objects with bottom objects]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if ((!SL || SM) && (!TL || TM)) ...
```

ie: the source must be empty or take multiple lines and the target must be empty or take multiple lines

Comment: I was able to simplify it a bit more but your example is definitely the simplest and most elegant for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at these two lines

```
(!sourceHasLines && !sourceCanMultiply && targetHasLines && targetCanMultiply)

(!sourceHasLines && sourceCanMultiply && targetHasLines && targetCanMultiply)
```

if any of them are true, we are going to draw a line

let us take

```
a = source has lines
A = source can multiply
b = target has lines
B = target can multiply
```

the above two lines become

```
(1) ~a AND ~ A AND b AND B
(2) ~a AND A AND b AND B
```

we are using (1)AND(2) for decision, which makes A (Source can multiply) DONT CARE when source does not have lines.

Hence Those two lines can be replaced with

```
(!sourceHasLines && targetHasLines && targetCanMultiply)
```

Now your code becomes

```
if ((!sourceHasLines && !targetHasLines)
    || (sourceHasLines && sourceCanMultiply && !targetHasLines) 
    || (sourceHasLines && sourceCanMultiply && targetHasLines && targetCanMultiply) 
    || (!sourceHasLines && targetHasLines && targetCanMultiply)) {    
    connection = self.connect($source, $target);
}
```

It can be further simplified to just

```
if ((!sourceHasLines || sourceCanMultiply) && (!targetHasLines || targetCanMultiply )) {    
    connection = self.connect($source, $target);
}
```

Comment: It was helpful seeing how you were able to combine the last two conditions into just one, and then coming to the same understanding as @Hurelu. Since Hurelu answered first, I'll accept that answer, but your answer was equally helpful. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply algebra to reduce the logic of your code:

Supposing:

```
A = sourceHasLines;
B = targetHasLines;
C = sourceCanMultiply;
D = targetCanMultiply;
```

it would translate in:

```
if ((!A && !B) ||
  (A && C && !B) ||
  (A && C && B && D) ||
  (!A && !C && B && D) || 
  (!A && C && B && D)) {
    // Create a line only if one of the above comparisons succeeds
    connection = self.connect($source, $target);
}
```

that would translate using algebra in:

```
(!A * !B) + ( A * C * !B ) + ( A * C * B * D) + ( !A * !C * B * D ) + ( !A * C * B * D )
```

Applying some maths:

```
!A * ( !B + ( B * D ) ) + A * C * ( !B + ( B * D ) )

( !B + ( B * D ) ) * ( !A + ( A * C ) ) 

(!A + C) * ( !B + D)
```

Hence:

```
if(!sourceHasLines || sourceCanMultiply) && ( !targetHasLines || targetCanMultiply)) {
    connection = self.connect($source, $target);
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not going to pretend that I understand your mathematical conclusion, I will admit it looks amazing and I'm certainly inspired to learn more about the concept(s). Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, just a bit of refactoring applying boolean algebra.